# Como imprimir múltiplos de N num intervalo?

Tags: python, string, algoritmo

O programa deve receber como entrada três valores N, A, e B, e deve imprimir os múltiplos de N contidos no intervalo entre A e B. Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira, mas está dando errado:

```
N = int(raw_input())
A = int(raw_input())
B = int(raw_input())
x = range(A, B + 1, N)
try:
    for i in range(A, B + 1, N):
        if x == [1]:
            print 'INEXISTENTE'
        else:
            print i 
except:
    if x == [1]:
        print 'INEXISTENTE'
```

Caso não existam múltiplos de N no intervalo dado, o programa deve imprimir "INEXISTENTE". O código funciona para alguns valores, mas para outros, como por exemplo 3, 5, 9 (N, A e B, respectivamente), ele não funciona.
Outro código tentado:

```
N = int(raw_input())
A = int(raw_input())
B = int(raw_input())
x = range(A, B + 1, N)
for i in range(A, B + 1, N):
    if i % N == 0:
        print i
```

Também funciona par alguns valores e para outros não.

Atualização:

```
N = int(raw_input())
A = int(raw_input())
B = int(raw_input())
x = range(A, B + 1)

for i in range(A, B + 1):
    if i % N == 0:
        print i
    elif x == []:
        print 'INEXISTENTE'
```

Este último código também não funciona. Se x não possuir valores, ou seja, se não existirem múltiplos no intervalo, o programa deveria imprimir 'INEXISTENTE', caso as entradas fossem, por exemplo, 12, 1 e 10, onde não existem múltiplos de 12 entre 1 e 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte maneira:

```
N = int(raw_input())
A = int(raw_input())
B = int(raw_input())
for i in range(A, B + 1):
    if i % N == 0:
        print i
if N > B:
    print 'INEXISTENTE'
```

Obrigado pelas dicas!

Answer (score 1):

Em Python há um operador bem bacana que pode te ajudar nessa tarefa: `%`. Ele retorna o resto da divisão de um número pelo outro. Experimente:

```
>>> 4 % 2
0
>>> 5 % 2
1
```

Dessa forma, se você quer saber se um número é múltiplo de outro, basta comparar o resultado da operação com `0`:

```
if x % y == 0:
    print('é múltiplo')
else:
    print('não é múltiplo')
```

Portanto, uma possível maneira de realizar o seu exercício seria:

```
n = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

for x in range(a, b):
    if x % n == 0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print('Inexistente')
```

Obs.: Troque `input` por `raw_input` e range por `xrange` se estiver utilizando Python 2.

Comment: Utilizando seu código, usando como entrada: 3, 5, 9, ele imprime apenas o número 6, e também imprime 'Inexistente' três vezes. A saída esperada seria apenas 6 e 9, um em cada linha. O 'Inexistente' só se aplica em entradas do tipo 12, 1, 10, onde entre 1 e 10 não existem múltiplos de 12.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa garantir que o começo do seu range seja divisível por N:

```
A, B, N = [int(raw_input()) for _ in xrange(3)]
multiplos = xrange(A + N - (A % N), B + 1, N)
print '\n'.join(map(str, multiplos)) if len(multiplos) > 0 else 'INEXISTENTE'
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Minha solução também funciona quando não existirem múltiplos, [pode conferir](https://repl.it/CCKy/0).

Answer (score 0):

O meu rodou assim no Python 3:

```
N = int(input())
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
for i in range(A, B + 1):
    if i % N == 0:
        print (i)
if N > B:
    print ('INEXISTENTE')
```

Comment: Considere explicar um pouco melhor por que o seu código funciona.